# Is there a way to make the navbar dropdown expand below a collapsed navbar?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a `react-bootstrap` navbar with a dropdown menu that stays shown when the navbar is collapsed. In other words, the `basic-nav-dropdown` does not hide like `home` and `link` below. I have accomplished this with the following, but there is an issue with the dropdown when the navbar is collapsed.

```
<Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
  <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
  <Nav className="mr-auto">
    <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Divider />
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
    </NavDropdown>
</Nav>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="mr-auto">
      <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
    </Nav>
    <Form inline>
      <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
      <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
    </Form>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

Here is what it looks like when the drop down is opened and the navbar is expanded. The dropdown show results below navbar and the results do not affect the presentation of the navbar. This is expected.

[image: Expected]

Here is what happens when the drop down is opened and the navbar is collapsed. **The dropdown does not fall below the navbar, and instead expands the navbar.** I would like the dropdown the behave the same as when the navbar is expanded.

[image: Actual]

**Is there a way to make the navbar dropdown expand *below* a collapsed navbar?**

I've also tried removing the `<Nav className="mr-auto/>` surrounding `<NavDropDown>` and while that does fix the problem, it introduces new problems as the navdropdown links are not similarly formatted as `home` and `link`, and also aligned to the center, not to the left as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a default behavior of `react-bootstrap` that, when `Navbar` is `collapsed` and contains `Dropdown` it will expand in `Navbar` only with following `CSS`,

```
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
}
```

You can just change the `CSS` to get desired output as,

```
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-emk8d?fontsize=14)